# Jenkins MacOS slave lost connect

Tags: macos, jenkins, nodes

I face to face with this problem a lot of times in JEnkins, and can't resolve it. I have got MacOS machine and the following output

```
  <===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>channel started
  Slave.jar version: 2.36
 This is a Unix slave
 Evacuated stdout
  Slave successfully connected and online
  May 20, 2014 9:43:04 AM hudson.Proc$LocalProc join
 WARNING: Process leaked file descriptors. See http://wiki.jenkins-      ci.org/display/JENKINS/Spawning+processes+from+build for more information
     java.lang.Exception
at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.join(Proc.java:329)
at hudson.Launcher$RemoteLaunchCallable$1.join(Launcher.java:1003)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler$RPCRequest.perform(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:299)
at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler$RPCRequest.call(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:280)
at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler$RPCRequest.call(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:239)
at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:118)
at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:328)
at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
     ERROR: Connection terminated
     java.io.IOException: Unexpected termination of the channel
at hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:50)
     Caused by: java.io.EOFException
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(ObjectInputStream.java:2576)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1295)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:349)
at hudson.remoting.Command.readFrom(Command.java:92)
at hudson.remoting.ClassicCommandTransport.read(ClassicCommandTransport.java:71)
at hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:48)
     ERROR: [05/20/14 17:04:49] [SSH] Error deleting file.
      java.io.IOException: Sorry, this connection is closed.
at com.trilead.ssh2.transport.TransportManager.sendMessage(TransportManager.java:647)
at com.trilead.ssh2.channel.ChannelManager.openSessionChannel(ChannelManager.java:581)
at com.trilead.ssh2.Session.<init>(Session.java:41)
at com.trilead.ssh2.Connection.openSession(Connection.java:1129)
at com.trilead.ssh2.Connection.exec(Connection.java:1541)
at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher.afterDisconnect(SSHLauncher.java:1165)
at hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer$2.onClosed(SlaveComputer.java:443)
at hudson.remoting.Channel.terminate(Channel.java:799)
at hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:69)
     Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:168)
at com.trilead.ssh2.crypto.cipher.CipherInputStream.fill_buffer(CipherInputStream.java:41)
at com.trilead.ssh2.crypto.cipher.CipherInputStream.internal_read(CipherInputStream.java:52)
at com.trilead.ssh2.crypto.cipher.CipherInputStream.getBlock(CipherInputStream.java:79)
at com.trilead.ssh2.crypto.cipher.CipherInputStream.read(CipherInputStream.java:108)
at com.trilead.ssh2.transport.TransportConnection.receiveMessage(TransportConnection.java:232)
at com.trilead.ssh2.transport.TransportManager.receiveLoop(TransportManager.java:682)
at com.trilead.ssh2.transport.TransportManager$1.run(TransportManager.java:480)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
     [05/20/14 17:04:49] [SSH] Connection closed.
     ERROR: [05/20/14 17:04:49] slave agent was terminated
     java.io.IOException: Unexpected termination of the channel
at hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:50)
     Caused by: java.io.EOFException
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(ObjectInputStream.java:2576)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1295)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:349)
at hudson.remoting.Command.readFrom(Command.java:92)
at hudson.remoting.ClassicCommandTransport.read(ClassicCommandTransport.java:71)
at hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:48)
```

After reboot the node it;s ok for a little bit, abd then again